# Error with Soap :SOAP body does not match

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

error message is

> The root element '{http://webservice.eis.tg}selectData' found within the SOAP body does not match the name and namespace of any message defined in the WSDL file.

this is my code

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
String URL = "http://202.122.131.25/EISDatagetDB";
String NameSpace = "http://webservice.eis.tg";

String MethodName = "selectData";
String SoapAction = "selectData";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NameSpace,MethodName);
request.addProperty("fromdate","201201");

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

try{                
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SoapAction, envelope);
         if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
                String str= ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
                Log.i("Soap", str);
                System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++"+str);
                tv1.setText(str);
         } else {
               SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                Log.d("WS", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
                Results = resultsRequestSOAP;
                data = Results.toString();
                System.out.println(data);
                tv1.setText(data);        
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("---------------------"+e);
                tv1.setText(""+e);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Please check xml at: `http://202.122.131.25/EISDatagetDB?wsdl`

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: your SoapAction is wrong. please check this http://android-spirit.blogspot.in/2013/07/consume-net-webservice-in-android.html for more details

Answer (score 0):

Can you make these two changes in your code?

Try to change

```
String URL = "http://202.122.131.25/EISDatagetDB";
```

to

```
String URL = "http://57.59.36.25:80/EISDatagetDB";
```

because the endpoint address is indicated in element

```
<wsdlsoap:address location="http://57.59.36.25:80/EISDatagetDB"/>
```